# AngularJS and ExpressJS Routing issue?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am using Angular, express, nodeJS for web application development.

**Anuglar code:**

```
'use strict';
//
 Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
    $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  }]).config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);;


angular.module('modelDemo', []).
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        controller: 'AuthorListCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
    });
     $routeProvider.
    when('/view1', {
        controller: 'MyCtrl1',
        templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html'
    });
   $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'})
});

var app = angular.module('app', ['myApp', 'modelDemo']);
```

**Express code**

```
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 2000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', wine.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', wine.partials);
app.get('/wines', wine.findAll);
// / app.get('/view1', wine.index);
app.get('/wines/:id', wine.findById);
app.post('/wines', wine.addWine);
app.put('/wines/:id', wine.updateWine);
app.delete('/wines/:id', wine.deleteWine);
app.get('/view1', wine.partials);
//app.get('/view1/:name', wine.partials);
```

2)

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
   console.log("request url---"+req.url);
   res.render('partials/' + req.params.name);
};

exports.partials = function(req, res) {
   console.log("request url---"+req.url);
   console.log(req.params.name);
   res.render('partials/' + req.params.name);
};
```

Project folder Structure:
[image: Folder stru]

When I tried to access this application by using following url, 
http://www.domain:2000/view1

i am getting following error,

> Error: Failed to lookup view "partials/undefined"
>       at Function.app.render (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:494:17)
>       at ServerResponse.res.render (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:756:7)
>       at exports.partials (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\routes\wines.js:104:9)
>       at callbacks (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
>       at param (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
>       at pass (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
>       at Router._dispatch (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
>       at Object.router (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
>       at next (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:190:15)
>       at resume (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:60:7)

Please let me know if you need more info on it

Comment: What is the code pointed here (d:\era\startup\learnnod\restfull_angular2\routes\wines.js:104:9) at callbacks

Comment: Added wines.js:104 code in the Quesiton,

Comment: you might want to remove app.set('view engine', 'jade');

Comment: After removing view engine, got this error Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to handle the routes in both your angular code and your express code. In order to get it to work as expected, you need to direct all non-partial/non-api routes to your index.html file.

Try doing something like this:

**wine.js** (your express route file)

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/public/index.html"); // updated to reflect dir structure
};
```

**app.js** (your express app file)

```
...
// make this your last route and remove your '/view1' route
app.get('*', wine.index);
...
```

Comment: No I don't want use Jade in this project

Comment: Does it means yourdirectory = public, as per my folder structure shown in my Question

Comment: I did worked for me. Thanks :) But I did not understand why app.get("*",...) is requried

Comment: It is because, all page requests need to be sent to your index.html file. Once your app has loaded, Angular will use pushState to manipulate the URL and handle routing. However, if you were to refresh the page or deeplink into an Angular route, Express would attempt to handle the routing. Sending it to the index on all routes will allow Angular to handle the routing.

Comment: sorry. I missed the chat request

Answer (score 0):

In your wine.js you are using parameter `name`, but in your routes you have commented the part.

```
app.get('/view1', wine.partials);
//app.get('/view1/:name', wine.partials);
```

Since you have not specified the param `:name` in route, when you try to access it with `req.params.name` it gives undefined. And you look for a file `undefined` that does not exist.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "partials/undefined" at Function.app.render
```

You probably want `res.render('partials/view1');`

Comment: No it will not work. I have tried that option too. Still got same error. I think, there is mismatch between anuglr router and express router

Comment: /view1/:name would not match `http://www.domain:2000/view1` . Are you passing some variable for name to test it? It is an express router error.

Comment: yes, as per angular router definition view1 = partials/partial1.html. That means, when u say /view1, it is nothing but a, www.domain.com/partial/partials.html.

Comment: Express router has no knowledge of angular router. So you would have to give the correct path yourself. Try `res.render('partials/partial1');`

Comment: Error: Failed to lookup view "partials/partial1", When app.get('/view1', wine.partials) is called, it will call exports.partials = function(req, res) { res.render('partials/partial1')}. I think here, is the problem.

Comment: render takes views from view folder. If you are just using static files then it should be from public folder.